# How does node_module resolve dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Suppose I have an `xyz` library (which i installed using `npm install xyz --save`) and project `abc`

How does node module determine if the dependency should be in

`abc/node_modules` or `abc/node_modules/xyz/node_modules`?

Comment: packages contain a `package.json` that contains the dependecies, so in your example, `abc/node_modules/xyz/package.json` contains the dependecies, that nodejs installs with the dependecies of the dependecy and so on until there's no more dependencies missing

Comment: so are you saying `abc/node_modules/xyz/node_modules` will contain all the dependency of xyz? if yes? then no, that's not true. like try it on your end?

Comment: depends on the configuration on that package, but usually if the version is different than the one already installed, it will store the package on xyz/node_module, if it's the same version, it would just use the one on the main root/node_modules/ folder

Comment: *probably still not true. I made a lib just for the sake of experiment and I noticed it to be in abc/node_modules instead of abc/node_modules/xyz/node_modules

Comment: it uses the main forlder (root/abc) if the lib doesn't exist, if it does, it uses the one installed only if the version is the same, if not the same version, the package will let the one on the root/node_modules untouched and store it on node_modules/xyz/node_modules. Try creating a dependeancy of a  lib that already exists in the root/node_modules folder instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Module is placed in nested `node_modules` if there's a non-compatible version in the "root" `node_modules`.

What iRohitBhatia is saying in the comments to your question, is partially true. But the important factor is not the version alone - but the version compatibility.

---

Example:

[axios@0.21.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) is dependent on [follow-redirects@^1.14.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/follow-redirects)

If you define your `package.json` like this

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "0.21.1"
    }
}
```

it installs both on the same level.

```
ls node_modules
axios
follow-redirects
```

```
ls node_modules/axios
# there is no nested `node_modules`
```

But if you have a non-compatible version of `follow-redirects` in your `node_modules`, it installs the compatible version to the nested `node_modules/axios/node_modules`.

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "follow-redirects": "1.0.0",
        "axios": "0.21.1"
    }
}
```

```
ls node_modules
axios
debug
follow-redirects  # the non-compatible `1.0.0` version
ms
```

```
ls node_modules/axios/node_modules
follow-redirects  # the compatible version
```